# How do I reference a dylib?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, frameworks, dylib

I have an application written in platform-independent C++ which has been primarily developed on Windows. I'm now trying to get it up and running on a Mac but I seem to be lost in how to link to the Mac version of a third-party library I'm using. I added the library's include and lib folders to header and library search paths respectively and it compiles/links but upon running dies with the following:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libsfml-system-d.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jdoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foobar-fonhiddwdwvgqygcegiffqkontxi/Build/Products/Debug/Foobar.app/Contents/MacOS/Foobar
  Reason: image not found`

I can get it to run by putting the dylibs in /usr/lib but I don't think this is a good idea for distribution. How can I include the dylib inside my app bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a copy-files build phase that copies the dylib into the Frameworks folder inside the app bundle.  (When you Get Info on a copy files build phase, Frameworks is one of the destination choices.)